# php-fpm package not available, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, ubuntu-14.04

I try to install the package php5-fpm on dist Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, nginx. But I get this message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package php5-fpm is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php5-fpm' has no installation candidate
```

I have search a lot what could be wrong and some answer stating that not all the right path's are in the "sources.list" file. I have uncomment lines where path's (URLs) where commented out. My "sources.list" file now looks like this:

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted


## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu saucy partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu saucy partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

How come that I cant install "php5-fpm" and how do I solve it?

Comment: Did you do an `apt-get update` after activating the `universe` repo?

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to do `apt-get update` as everything seems to be ok.